Boost Asio: How to run a single handler in multiple independent strands?
Imagine in a multithreaded context we have three or more independent strands each serializing access to a different resource:
boost::asio::io_context ioc;
auto io_ex = ioc.get_executor();

auto strand_a = boost::asio::make_strand(io_ex);
auto strand_b = boost::asio::make_strand(io_ex);
auto strand_c = boost::asio::make_strand(io_ex);

// TODO: schedule handler on all three strands

std::jthread threads[3]; // provide enough threads to serve strands in parallel
for (auto& thread : threads)
    thread = std::jthread{ [&]() { ioc.run(); }};

How can we archive to run a single handler in all strands at once, allowing to safely access all resources simultaneously from within this single hander?
Effectively I want to archive that
strand_a.running_in_this_thread()
    && strand_b.running_in_this_thread()
    && strand_c.running_in_this_thread()

is true in some handler.

please show a [mre]  of what you're trying to do. I'm not sure what you're asking but if you need to share a single resource you can only have one strand

@AlanBirtles sorry I should have made clear the strands each serialize access to a different resource. I updated the first sentence. I hope the problem is now clearer.

I don't think this is possible

As seen in my other question apparently (to my surprise) it's possible to have a handler run on two strands at least. I hope the answers there will help me get a better understanding of how that is possible while it's generally not possible to execute a handler on multiple strands.

I must admit, here I was also mildly surprised.
While it made sense that one can be on more than one strand, I wouldn't rely on this property in my design. For multiple reasons:

awaiting multiple locks is usually a bad idea, regardless of the asynchrony; it very easily leads to deadlocks
the overhead imposed by the scheduler having to resolve the strand criteria (by multiple repeated suspend/resumes) is going to be non-negligable
there is no dedicated control interface in Asio designed to control multi-strand conditions

In the end I suppose my previous superficial observations that multiple strands occur in various usage scenarios are unspecified behavior: it comes down to Asio

promises to run a handler on its bound executor, which means that a handler bound to strand s is definitely executed on that strand.
it does not promise that any other handler is not executed on that strand¹

We have to realize that "executors" are not concrete things that contain or own work, and neither are strands. They're abstractions and the scheduler merely needs to execute the handlers according to the specified rules which makes the work behave as if they were the concrete thing they represent. This gives an implementation enormous freedom to optimize or change implementations.
To document my understanding better compare these programs:

with #define SWITCH(ex) post(bind_executor(ex, asio::deferred)) some asserts fail
with #define SWITCH(ex) dispatch(bind_executor(ex, asio::deferred)) all asserts pass](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/276d40bc7a82160a)

This reinforces my believe that while this incidental overlapping of strands is observed it is not to be relied on.
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ioc;

// #define SWITCH(ex) post(bind_executor(ex, asio::deferred))
#define SWITCH(ex) dispatch(bind_executor(ex, asio::deferred))

    auto a   = make_strand(ioc);
    auto b   = make_strand(ioc);
    auto c   = make_strand(ioc);
    auto onA = [&a] { return a.running_in_this_thread(); };
    auto onB = [&b] { return b.running_in_this_thread(); };
    auto onC = [&c] { return c.running_in_this_thread(); };

    co_spawn(
        ioc,
        [&] -> asio::awaitable<void> {
            assert(not(onA() or onB() or onC()));

            co_await SWITCH(a);
            assert(not onC());
            assert(not onB());
            assert(onA());

            co_await SWITCH(b);
            assert(not onC());
            assert(onB());
            assert(onA());

            co_await SWITCH(c);
            assert(onC());
            assert(onB());
            assert(onA());
        },
        asio::detached);

    ioc.join();
}


¹
A similar caveat is documented under strand guarantees:

Remarks
The implementation makes no guarantee that handlers posted or dispatched through different strand objects will be invoked concurrently.

